# Align arrows in a column of different cells of a table

Tags: tables, arrows, alignment

How can I align the `\rightarrow` symbols in the cells below?

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{L{3cm}C{2.6cm}C{2.6cm}C{2.6cm}}
\toprule
 Norwegian $\rightarrow$ Swedish & ? & ? & ?  \\
 Swedish $\rightarrow$ Norwegian & ? & ? & ? \\
...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Couldn't you just add extra columns for that? You will almost certainly get a nice answer if you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 4):

with simple basic `tabular` environment with `l` and `c` columns' specifiers:

edite: reduce space around `\rightarrow` and added example with`r` column specifier for the first column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l@{\,}c@{\,}l} % <---
    \toprule
 Amazon     & $\rightarrow$ & Twitter   \\
 Twitter    & $\rightarrow$ & Amazon    \\
 Norwegian  & $\rightarrow$ & Swedish   \\
 Swedish    & $\rightarrow$ & Norwegian \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{r@{\,}c@{\,}l} % <---
    \toprule
 Amazon     & $\rightarrow$ & Twitter   \\
 Twitter    & $\rightarrow$ & Amazon    \\
 Norwegian  & $\rightarrow$ & Swedish   \\
 Swedish    & $\rightarrow$ & Norwegian \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebastiano, good morning! thank you very much!

Comment: Nice solution. However, how do you solve the issue I'm also having with the arrows having too much white space around them?

Comment: @pir You could use `{tabular}{rcl}` and then have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350636/89662)

Comment: @pir,  see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same issue. Here's a solution using extra columns as also suggested by @marmot in a comment. However, I'm not completely satisfied with this solution as there's quite a bit of space between the text and arrows. If anyone can find a way to flexibly adjust the amount of space between the text and the arrows, then that would be awesome. I can't just reduce the column size as the text then becomes multi-line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\small
\label{tab:da_balanced}
\begin{adjustbox}{center}
\begin{tabular}{L{1.5cm}L{0.5cm}L{1.5cm}}
\toprule
 Amazon & $\rightarrow$ & Twitter \\
 Twitter & $\rightarrow$ & Amazon \\
 Norwegian & $\rightarrow$ & Swedish \\
 Swedish & $\rightarrow$ & Norwegian \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One could also use the `\rightarrow` command in the column definition of the table to avoid repeating this command in every line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l@{\,$\rightarrow$\,}l}
    \toprule
       Norwegian  & Swedish   \\
       Swedish    & Norwegian \\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]